# How can I convert a json nested dataset or a xml nested dataset into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, json, list

As the title suggests the test case below can give an idea of what my task is.
Suppose I have a json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "978-0062562",
    "name": "The Hidden Oracle",
    "author": "Rick Riordan",
    "details": [
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "published_year": 2017,
        "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion"
      }
    ,
     
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "published_year": 2018,
        "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion"
      }
  ]
},
  {
    "id": "978-148474",
    "name": "Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard",
    "author": "Rick Riordan",
    "details": [
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "published_year": 2016,
        "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My expected output is:

```
[('978-0062562', 'The Hidden Oracle', 'Rick Riordan', [('Fantasy', 2017, 'Disney-Hyperion'), ('Fantasy', 2018, 'Disney-Hyperion')]), ('978-148474', 'Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard', 'Rick Riordan', [('Fantasy', 2016, 'Disney-Hyperion')])]
```

I wanted to find a more generic approach, which might work for any similar dataset. I even tried recursively iterating through the contents to reach something but failed.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You tag with xml, there is no xml?

Answer (score 3):

Here is recursion method to convert the list:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "id": "978-0062562",
        "name": "The Hidden Oracle",
        "author": "Rick Riordan",
        "details": [
            {
                "genre": "Fantasy",
                "published_year": 2017,
                "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion",
            },
            {
                "genre": "Fantasy",
                "published_year": 2018,
                "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "978-148474",
        "name": "Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard",
        "author": "Rick Riordan",
        "details": [
            {"genre": "Fantasy", "published_year": 2016, "publisher": "Disney-Hyperion"}
        ],
    },
]


def convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [convert(v) for v in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return tuple(convert(v) for v in obj.values())
    else:
        return obj


print(convert(lst))
```

Prints:

```
[
    (
        "978-0062562",
        "The Hidden Oracle",
        "Rick Riordan",
        [("Fantasy", 2017, "Disney-Hyperion"), ("Fantasy", 2018, "Disney-Hyperion")],
    ),
    (
        "978-148474",
        "Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard",
        "Rick Riordan",
        [("Fantasy", 2016, "Disney-Hyperion")],
    ),
]
```